# How can I set kernel parameters for a specific installation involving os-prober?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, os-prober

Beside Ubuntu i also have an Arch installation. I plan to maintain the grub-configuration from my Ubuntu. The whole `update-grub` - `grub-mkconfig` - `os-prober`-chain works just fine.
I know I can set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` for options to be passed to the kernel in `/etc/default/grub`. But how would I possibly specify that per kernel / kernels on a specific partition?

Neat would be having a little text-file beside a kernel image that is evaluated by the tool-chain, but i guess that's some serious hacking through the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the op-prober entry into 40_custom and edit to have the paramaters you want. Then turn off os-prober.

```
sudo cp -a /boot/grub/grub.cfg /boot/grub/grub.cfg.backup
gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Copy them to and edit to have only entries you want:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

Then do:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If above works then turn off os-prober.

In /etc/default/grub I added this:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true

or turn off executeable bit

```
sudo chmod a-x /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
sudo update-grub
```